# Issue with getting the index of a spreadsheet on GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram-bot

I wrote a telegram bot that connects to a spreadsheet. The user has to give his name and the bot is supposed to look it up from the sheet. If the name is on the sheet (i.e `lookUpRange.indexOf(text) > -1`), the bot emails me this string `"you're on the scores tab."` The email is going through and this is working fine.

The problem is, the second piece of code is not working: if  `lookUpRange.indexOf(text)` returns anything less than 1, it should email me that I'm not on the scores tab. I only have 5 names on the scores tab and anything outside them would return -1 if you run `lookUpRange.indexOf(text)`. But no email is going through.

I've tried setting up `var text` with a random string and logged it to make sure it returns -1. It does.

```
function doPost(e) {
//parses user's text 
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  var id = contents.message.from.id; 
  var text = contents.message.text; 
  var first_name = contents.message.from.first_name; 
//locates text in the spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Scores");
  var lookUpRange = flatten(ss.getDataRange().getValues());
  var index = lookUpRange.indexOf(text); 

  if (lookUpRange.indexOf(text) > -1){
    GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "you're on the scores tab", text + " from " + first_name);
  }
  else {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail(), "you're not on the scores tab", text + " from " + first_name);
  }
}
```

Comment: do you know how to use the debugger to step through this as it executes? the little bug button

Comment: then you can see the vars as they change. btw i’d put index in the conditional instead of calling lookupRange.indexOf again.

Comment: There's a big difference between your stated issue ("if index < 1") and the code ("if index < -1"). Which is it? Have you checked Stackdriver logs to see if there are errors when your script runs?

Comment: I have a question, how does doPost know what the active spreadsheet is?  doPost is run from a web app.

Comment: @TheWizEd Any script(web-app or otherwise), if bound to a spreadsheet, returns the bound spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheMaster a bound script is not a web app.  I have exeperience with both but don't know how a web app can know the active spreadsheet.  I can understand using a web app with openById but not this way.

Comment: @TheWizEd You can publish a bound script as a web-app just like a standalone script. The only requirements for a web-app is a doGet()/doPost() function. Nothing else. As long as a script is bound, you can get active spreadsheet.